Too many [windows] to see through
I noticed we have tags for vim-windows and microsoft-windows. Both of them make sense. I'm a bit puzzled by windows next to them. This tag not having any usage guidance doesn't help to make it much clearer.
Unless I'm missing something, there should not be a tag windows.
It's only 9 questions so I'll go through them in the next few days and change tags to either of the other two or remove it altogether.
As I understand it, the system will clean up the tag once it's not used anymore.
With windows being a loaded term, are there any precautions we can take not to make it come back? Create a synonym? Forbid it altogether? Write a "DO NOT USE!" note? Crucifixes and garlic to prevent it from rising from its grave?
PS: From the link in Ben's answer, I understand this question should be tagged burnination-request. It seems there's no such tag on Vi and Vim Meta. Even if there was, I'd have missed it.
I already regret having opened the Pandora's box of tags.
Update: the tag windows is gone. I edited it out of all 9 questions. FWIW, there was not a single instance where vim-windows was meant. It was either meant to be microsoft-windows or seemingly given randomly.

“Are there precautions” Probably. I’ll have to dig through the help/mod manuals again :)

We can create a synonym, but in this case I worry it's ambiguous. I've asked if there's a way to "ban" a tag

Yes, I thought about the ambiguity problem. I would argue that - since this site is about Vim - the Vim meaning trumps the operating system. Even then, it would probably cause confusion.

Whee, my first-ever question on any SE and it gets [featured]! My mom will be so proud.

I'm wholeheartedly in favor of burninating the windows tag.
We can make windows a synonym of either vim-windows or microsoft-windows. I lean towards the former, but the ambiguity may cause some issues. (If you notice a vim-windows where microsoft-windows was meant, fix it.)
Given the numbers in the questions, I've created a windows to microsoft-windows synonym.

Thanks for your research and reply. I'm asking myself if your option 1) is that much of an improvement over the situation we have now (i.e. if you notice [tag:windows], fix it). It should also be noted that we see a lot of questions featuring something like "btw, I'm on Windows" and the tag where it doesn't matter the least. It's a problematic tag to begin with.

@Friedrich well, with the synonym using windows would automatically add vim-windows instead, I think, but your point is well-taken

Those were two points muddled together: 1) a tag synonym (to [vim-windows]) may only shift the problem and 2) [microsoft-windows] is often tagged where it shouldn't be. Maybe I'm overthinking, we'll just have to adjust tags every now and then.

Your answer suffers the minor problem that it outlines two options and we don't know whether a vote was meant for 1) or 2).Having read the linked content, I would not pursue 2) for now. The answer explicitly mentions repeated burninations of a tag so I'd just keep it in mind (this Q&A should do as our collective memory).

Ah, yes, darn. And no way to split them because of the votes. Let me split it anyway and make (2) a separate answer.

This is the way to go, then. I'd vote for a tag synonym but unfortunately, I don't have the score to do so. It seems the only thing left for me to do is to accept this answer.

@Friedrich you should have the rep (1250?) to propose a synonym

I do have the rep but I don't have a score of 5 in the respective tag. In fact, I have 0 :-)

Like the other answer, burninate.
Then, block the tag windows. This is more work but may be more effective.
